# Last few times I bought "fresh" stone fruit the stone was gone

Tags: fruit

The last few times I bought plums or nectarines the stone appeared to have rotted out.

However, when eating one today upon noticing this same effect I noted what appeared to be a rectangular cut out where they stem had been attached to the fruit, this then made me think has this been mechanically removed to be sold off elsewhere to increase corporate profits.

I'm located in queensland Australia.

Has anyone else noticed this and does anyone know the reasoning behind it.

Comment: I have never seen this. Where do you live?

Comment: Pictures, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what the value of a stone would be anyway. Perhaps it's intended to be a convenience but you'd think they'd advertise the fact, also it would spoil much quicker

Comment: How big was the rectangular cut out?

Comment: And was that no stone left? Or were there some stone fragments inside?

Comment: Sounds like a punch was used, but not sure why this would be done, it would greatly reduce shelf life.  I can only think of this being done for canning or processing and then surplus sold off.  Yes, if this was done in a very short period the center would look oxidized as if he stone had rotten out and would degrade the quality.  In some areas there have been fights over selling peach pit meat as almonds and nectarine kernels might also pass, but my experience with plums would be a smaller and more bitter product and I could only see this being done in a processing facility not for fresh saie.

Comment: at an estimate i'd say 5mmx3mm and some of the outer shell was still there but only a small amount

Comment: Would such treatment not make the fruit into a perishable foodstuff (->2/4 hour rule would need to be applied in commercial storage and handling) by most regulations?

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it, and I was told that the stone fruit pits are often sold to drug and other remedy companies. The young man I spoke with said that apricot pits, for example, have compounds useful in fighting or treating cancer. I'm not sure if that is why the pits are removed, but it makes a lot of sense to me. Removing the pit lessens the weight of the fruit, so someone must be buying that missing weight for as much as or more than the amount for which you are buying the rest of the fruit.

Comment: That sounds so weird. If somebody really wanted the pits, you'd imagine they could get all they want for almost free, no effort, at the cannery. I'm curious: are you also located in Queensland, Australia?